# Can't Sends Keys to Directed Paypal Login Page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a Auto-Fill bot for Paypal Checkout. The paypal login page is redirected from another website, so it is slightly different to the offical paypal login page, though the HTML is similar.

I've tried different methods like `switch to frame`, `scroll down`, `execute_script`. However, none of them are working and I'm not able to `send_keys`.

The same things working fine on the official Paypal login page as below:

https://www.paypal.com/signin/?country.x=US&locale.x=en_US

The one that I'm struggling with is:

https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=EC-1P412919U09359725#/checkout/login

Answer (score 1):

In your page there is one loader and after that your login options displays in `iframe` so first you need to put `ExplicitWait` until your frame get visible and then need to switch into that frame to perform action.

I have following code for the same in Java

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("injectedUl")));

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("injectedUl")));
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("asdsa");

driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
```

This is equivalent code in Python (Please make correction I'm not much familiar with python )

```
frame_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.name, "injectedUl"))
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.find_element_by_name("injectedUl"));
driver.find_element_by_id("email"))send_keys("abc@gmail.com");
driver.find_element_by_id("password")send_keys("asdsa");
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin")).click();
```

Comment: That Works! Thank You!  I tried the iframe but I directly used the name like driver.switchTo().frame("injectedUl"), don't know why this did not work.

Comment: `Frame()`  method require parameter as web element and you are sending as a. String that's why it was not working.