# Selenium: Unable to locate element on PayPal Login Page

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, paypal, automation

I am currently using a page object to represent the PayPal login page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) for automation purposes and no matter what I do I can't seem to click the Log In button on the page.
Here is what the page looks like: 
[image: Sanbox PayPal Login Page]
Here is my current page object representation of the PayPal login page:

```
public class PayPalLoginPage extends DesktopPage {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PayPalLoginPage.class);

    @FindBy(id = "email")
    private WebElement emailInput;

    @FindBy(id = "password")
    private WebElement passwordInput;

    @FindBy(id = "btnLogin")
    private WebElement loginButton;

    public PayPalLoginPage(BuildWebDriver driver, Wait<WebDriver> wait) {
        super(driver, wait);
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        LOG.debug("Setting email: " + email);
        setTextWithJavascript(emailInput, email);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        LOG.debug("Setting password: " + password);
        setTextWithJavascript(passwordInput, password);
    }

    public PayPalPaymentsPage clickLoginButton() {
        LOG.debug("Clicking 'Log In' Button.");
        clickWithJavascript(loginButton);

        return new PayPalPaymentsPage(driver, wait);
    }
}
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to interact with the input boxes for email / password and the Log In button. Getting errors such as: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btnLogin"}`

I've tried using the better way of setting the input fields with email / password via `webElement.sendKeys(String keys)` but that results in an error such as: `Stack Trace org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible`. Trying to wait for the visibility of the element times out. Javascript seems to be the only (and my last resort) in interacting with the page, but even the JavaScript is failing.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Javascript click?  Simple click works fine

Comment: Refer this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732688/cant-sends-keys-to-directed-paypal-login-page/42732853#42732853

Comment: @Tuks thanks, that was it. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The element you're trying to interact with is inside an iframe, so it's in a different document. You're going to need to find a way with Selenium to select inside an iframe.

Comment: You can use switch to frame method if elements are inside iframe.

Comment: The paypal checkout page is not inside an iframe, it's a page in of itself.

Comment: Yes. But the login section of the page is in an iframe.